# Is it possible to reduce my code anymore?

Tags: javascript, dry

**Here's my code.**

```js
function legalPeopleToDrive(people) {
  const myFilter = people
    .filter(p => p.age > 14)
    .map(p => {
      return p.name;
    });
  return myFilter;
}

const myObj = [
  { name: "John", age: 14 },
  { name: "Jim", age: 16 },
  { name: "Ben", age: 18 }
];

console.log(legalPeopleToDrive(myObj));
```

Pretty much, I'm just really curious as to see if it's possible to reduce this anymore. Can this be done also by just using one of these methods `filter()` or `map()`?

Comment: How much more DRY could it be? I don't see anything repeated.

Comment: You could use `reduce()` to do the mapping and filtering in one step.

Comment: [codereview.se] is the place to ask for advice on how to improve working code.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for when I asked this question! Thanks a ton! It's crazy how many methods there is in Javascript.

Comment: That said, `reduce` tends to be confusing IMHO, and your method is much clearer.

Comment: `const legalPeopleToDrive = people => people.reduce((a, p) => (p.age > 14 && a.push(p), a), [])` Yeah, it works, but I would leave some nasty remarks in a code review to make it readable. lol

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create the desired result by only iterating over the array once, which might be done with `.reduce`. You can also immediately return the call of the array method - no need to store it in a variable beforehand. Another option is to use an arrow function for concise return:

```js
const legalPeopleToDrive = people => people.reduce((a, p) => {
  if (p.age > 14) a.push(p.name);
  return a;
}, []);

const myObj = [
  { name: "John", age: 14 },
  { name: "Jim", age: 16 },
  { name: "Ben", age: 18 }
];

console.log(legalPeopleToDrive(myObj));
```

Still, your current code looks fine to me.

Comment: lol, just realized that the answer is in the title of the question.

Comment: If you use a ternary, you could reduce it even further. `people.reduce((a, p) => p.age > 14 ? a.concat(p.name) : a, [])`.

Comment: Thanks so much! I totally forgot about reduce(); Crazy how many methods are in Javascript.

Comment: @Barmar Hahahahahaha! What a coincidence.

Comment: @fubar, given large number of iterations, `concat()` will most likely to slow things down significantly since it needs to create new array (copy) every time. `people.reduce((a, p) => (p.age > 14 && a.push(p.name), a), []);` will be the most efficient with the same number of chars.

Comment: @niry, nice solution.

Answer (score 1):

### Answer:

To answer your question at the end, *"Can this be done also by just using one of these methods filter() or map()?"*: Yes - it can be done by only one of `filter` or `map`, however, it will not use `filter` or `map` as intended, and `reduce` or `forEach` is encouraged in this case.

```js
const legalPeopleToDrive = people => {
  const a = []; 
  people.map(p => {
    if (p.age > 14) {
      a.push(p.name);
    }
  });
  return a;
}

// An uber-short form would be:
// let legalPeopleToDrive = (people, a = []) => (people.map(p => p.age > 14 && a.push(p.name)), a);

const myObj = [
  { name: "John", age: 14 },
  { name: "Jim", age: 16 },
  { name: "Ben", age: 18 }
];

console.log(legalPeopleToDrive(myObj));
```

### Performance considerations:

Some of the other ideas on this page may result in higher latency in case of large sets or multiple iterations; in general, avoid creating new arrays inside the iteration, which is what `flatMap()` and `concat()` are doing or forcing you to do. Scanning the array twice with `filter()` and `map()` is also worse than `forEach()`, `for` loop, and `reduce()` without `concat()`.

```js
const funcs = [
  "people => people.flatMap(p => p.age > 14 ? [p.name] : []);",
  "people => people.reduce((a, p) => p.age > 14 ? a.concat(p.name) : a, []);",
  "people => {let a = []; people.map(p => p.age > 14 && a.push(p.name)); return a;};",
  "people => people.filter(p => p.age > 14).map(p => p.name);",
  "people => {let a = []; for (let p of people) p.age > 14 && a.push(p.name); return a;};",
  "people => people.reduce((a, p) => (p.age > 14 && a.push(p.name), a), []);",
  "people => {let a = []; people.forEach(p => p.age > 14 && a.push(p.name)); return a;};",
  "people => [...(function*(people){for (let p of people) if (p.age > 14) yield p.name;})(people)];",
].sort(_ => .5 - Math.random());

const myObj = [
  { name: "John", age: 14 },
  { name: "Jim", age: 16 },
  { name: "Ben", age: 18 }
];

for (let f of funcs) {
  const legalPeopleToDrive = eval(f);
  const start = new Date();
  for (let i=0;i<1000000;++i) legalPeopleToDrive(myObj);
  console.log(f, new Date() - start, 'ms'); //, legalPeopleToDrive(myObj));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for once, you could write the function in a somewhat more concise/compact way:

```
const legalPeopleToDrive = people => people.filter(p => p.age > 14).map(p => p.name);
```

> Can this be done also by just using one of these methods `filter()` or `map()`?

not with these methods, but:

```
const legalPeopleToDrive = people => people.flatMap(p => p.age > 14? p.name: []);
```

you can also return `Array.prototype` instead of creating an empty Array, but that would be longer again.

You could also write it as a iterator/generator function. Not really a way to shorten your code, but by sheer charcount, still shorter than your code:

```js
function* legalPeopleToDrive(people) {
  for (let p of people) if (p.age > 14) yield p.name;
}

const myObj = [
  { name: "John", age: 14 },
  { name: "Jim", age: 16 },
  { name: "Ben", age: 18 }
];

console.log([...legalPeopleToDrive(myObj)]);
```

just don't forget that your result is now an iterator, not an array.